# why are the div elements moving sideways on clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The objctive is to have the html organized by type of products and the objective is to show or hide div's by clicking on correspondent button.So i have 4 div named box with the container of each category organized inside. When i click in any of them, it open and shows the info regarding that selection, but the remaining options don't stay in their initial positions, moving to left or right, depending on the element choosed. i tried to use display:block, position: fixed/static/absolute, but without any sucess. no mather what, it allways move arround

HTML & JS

```js
     $('.top').on('click', function() {
       $parent_box = $(this).closest('.box');
       $parent_box.siblings().find('.bottom').hide();
       $parent_box.find('.bottom').toggle();

     });
```

```css
box {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
box a {
  display: block margin-top: 175px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  color: #1B3E90;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px
}
.bottom {
  margin-top: 35px;
  overflow: auto;
}
top:hover {
  color: #F89326;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  display: block
}
.top:target {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

  <a class="top"> Fardamentos e uniformes </a>
  <div class=" bottom" style="display: none;">

    <!--- ------------- introdução de frames --------------------- -->

    <div class="responsive1" id="img1">

      <div class="img">
        <a class="open" href="#">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" alt=" ">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">x</span>
        <h1>Box1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive1" id="img2">

      <div class="img">
        <a class="open" href="#">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" alt=" ">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal2">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close2">x</span>
        <h1>Box2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- --------------------Proxima Classe de produtos -->



<div class="box">
  <a class="top"> Bibs & Batas </a>
  <div class=" bottom" style="display: none;">
    <h1> bibs e Batas </h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- --------------------Proxima Classe de produtos -->
<div class="box">
  <a class="top"> Confeções Variadas </a>
  <div class=" bottom" style="display: none;">
    <h1> Confeções variadas </h1>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- --------------------Proxima Classe de produtos -->
<div class="box">
  <a class="top"> Equipamento Desportivo </a>
  <div class=" bottom" style="display: none;">
    <h1> Equipamento Desportivo </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

now, you might that my css might seem incomplete. well... i have tried a lot of options, and been adding and removing  code in the process.

No matter what, the divs simply don't stay fixed where's it's suposed to stay.
It's been 3 days since i came up with this issue, and i'm getting frustrated and desperate. any inputs would be much apretiated.

thanks

Comment: Curious and want to make sure, are you building a custom [modals](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)?

Comment: I was not. Probably that's what should be doing ... ?

Comment: Class definitions should start with dot, so check it in style section.

Comment: @Mr_sang I don't know, maybe? Your current result looks like [accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace) to me but to be honest, I don't quite get what are you trying to achieve. Probably a diagram/image would help. :S